# Android Gradle 3 facebook-login:4.29.0 dex merge error Program type already present

Tags: android, facebook, gradle, facebook-login, android-gradle-3.0

Hey I am trying to add the newest version of facebook-login:4.29.0 to my app. In doing so I updated to Gradle 3. I cannot resolve this dex merge. It only happens if I include the facebook-login library. Maybe I did something with the gradle 3 migration wrong? I have a few other facebook libraries that are likely causing the conflict. But this isn't like a merge error I've seen before. I've also done all the usual as clean and deleting the .gradle folder. Multidex is on. The com.facebook.android is added to proguard exceptions. I can't do a force merge resolution strategy as it's not a version missmatch. Had to cut a lot of the log out for character limits on SO. Works just fine if I don't include facebook.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.21.7'
    }
}



configurations.all {
    // check for updates every build
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')



    //crashlytics
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation('com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:2.3.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    // testing
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
    dependencies { testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+" }
    debugCompile 'com.jakewharton:process-phoenix:1.0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2') {
        exclude module: 'espresso-core'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'design'
    }

    // android
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'

    // payment
    implementation 'com.adyen.checkout:core:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:2.0.2'
    implementation 'io.card:android-sdk:5.4.1'
    implementation 'com.adyen.checkout:core:1.0.6'


    // leak canary
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5'
    stagingCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'

    // google play services
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:${firebaseVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${firebaseVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:${firebaseVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:${firebaseVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${firebaseVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:${firebaseVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:${firebaseVersion}"

    // dependency injection
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9'

    // networking
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'

    // data

    // rx
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxrelay:rxrelay:1.2.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.6'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'

    // rx-ui
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-design:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-appcompat-v7:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-recyclerview-v7:0.4.0'

    // ui

    // images
    implementation('com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.7.1') {
        // conflicts with Facebook SDK.
        exclude module: 'bolts-tasks'
    }
    implementation 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:1.3.1'

    // location
    implementation 'pl.charmas.android:android-reactive-location:0.8@aar'

    // event bus
    implementation 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.6'

    // deeplinking
    implementation 'tv.cntt:jauter:1.7'


    // social
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.29.0'

    //    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.18.0'{
    //        exclude "com.facebook.FacebookAuthorizationException"
    //    }

    implementation 'com.sromku:simple-fb:4.0.8'

    // loading library for startup
    implementation 'com.victor:lib:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.github.provigen:ProviGen-lib:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'

    // AndroidSwipeLayout
    implementation 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'

    // logging
    debugCompile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.5.0'
    debugCompile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'




    // recycler view\
    implementation 'eu.davidea:flexible-adapter:5.0.0-rc2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'


    stagingCompile("com.eee.android:analytics:${analyticsVersion}") { changing = true }
    releaseCompile("com.eee.android:analytics:${analyticsVersion}") { changing = true }
    println 'RELEASE Compiled remote version of analytics'
}




apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

// @see https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin
```

Result

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:...

at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1431)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.externalAwaitDone(ForkJoinTask.java:326)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doJoin(ForkJoinTask.java:391)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:719)
at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.forEach(ImmutableList.java:397)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransform.transform(DexMergerTransform.java:225)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:222)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:218)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:213)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1512.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
.....
.....
.....
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:53)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:71)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:58)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
...

at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:96)
at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:82)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:97)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:35)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
... 129 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: com.facebook.AccessTokenManager$1
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.resolveClassConflictImpl(ProgramClassCollection.java:61)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.lambda$create$44(ProgramClassCollection.java:22)
at java.util.Map.merge(Map.java:1175)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.create(ProgramClassCollection.java:22)
at com.android.tools.r8.graph.LazyLoadedDexApplication$Builder.build(LazyLoadedDexApplication.java:114)
at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:93)
at com.android.tools.r8.D8.runForTesting(D8.java:175)
at com.android.tools.r8.D8.runForTesting(D8.java:149)
at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:68)
at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:80)
... 132 more


:app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
        > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing
        .DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
...


* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:60)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:128)
at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:46)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:311)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:202)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:132)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:107)
at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
.....
.....
.....
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang
        .RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: ...

at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:213)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
... 102 more
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder
        .dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
...

at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransform.transform(DexMergerTransform.java:229)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:222)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:218)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
... 114 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging
dex archives: ...

at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.forEach(ImmutableList.java:397)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransform.transform(DexMergerTransform.java:225)
... 117 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
....

at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:96)
at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:82)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:97)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:35)
... 119 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: com.facebook.AccessTokenManager$1
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.resolveClassConflictImpl(ProgramClassCollection.java:61)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.lambda$create$44(ProgramClassCollection.java:22)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.create(ProgramClassCollection.java:22)
at com.android.tools.r8.graph.LazyLoadedDexApplication$Builder.build(LazyLoadedDexApplication.java:114)
at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:93)
at com.android.tools.r8.D8.runForTesting(D8.java:175)
at com.android.tools.r8.D8.runForTesting(D8.java:149)
at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:68)
at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:80)
... 121 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 35s
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing

```
implementation 'com.sromku:simple-fb:4.0.8'
```

fixed it. Guess it was some depreciated library. Just inherited this code base. I will need to update all the other dependencies and identify other such libraries.